# uudecode algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, uuencode, uudecode

i'm looking for a implementation of uudecode algorithm in javascript, anybody knows if any framework or native javascript implements this funcionality?

I'm trying to find the solution in the web and i cant find anything, if any can helps i would greatly appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this implementation](https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/_workbench/strings/convert_uudecode.js). However, there is a note mentioning that it doesn't work perfectly. I'll wager that not too many people still use uuencoding, so you might have to write one yourself to satisfy your needs.